# Rename a field in nested serializer - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to rename a field in my serializer, like this:

```py
class ExampleTwoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ExampleTwo
        exclude = ("some_field", "another_field")


class ExampleOneSerializer(CustomModelSerializer):
    new_fied = ExampleOneSerializer(source="example_model_field", many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ExampleOne
        exclude = ("some_field", "another_field")
```

But I get this error:

```sh
AttributeError at /api/example/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `new_field` on serializer `ExampleTwoSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `ExampleTwo` instance.
Original exception text was: 'ExampleTwo' object has no attribute 'new_fied'.
```

Comment: You need to provide more context. Is that when reading data ? writing data ? What data are written ? what do the models looks like ?

Comment: Hey @Linovia, thanx for support. Only read data. Basically I need to show data from a relationship model (ExampleOne is ForeignKey of the ExampleTwo) with other name.

Comment: Serializers use the dot notation for nested source. So it should be example_model.field